# Unity: Player Jumping Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a piece of code that is trying to get the player to jump between 2 boxes only Cube 1 (position on left side) and Cube 2 (on right side) by tapping.

The issue with the Move() function is that it starts jumping from Cube 1  to Cube 2, then Cube 2 back to Cube 1, but from this point on, the player jumps from Cube 1 to the left side the opposite of Cube 2.

The jump functions are working, but I think the logic is incorrect.

**Move:**

```
void Move(){
    int i = 0;
    while ((isGrounded == true) && (i < 10)) {

        if(atCube1 == true){
            JumpRight();
        }

        if(atCube2 == true){
          JumpLeft();
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

**OnCollisionEnter:**

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter");


    if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube 1"){
        Debug.Log ("++++++ C U B E 1   H I T ++++++++");

        atCube1 = true;
        isGrounded = true;

    }

    if(col.gameObject.name == "Cube 2"){

        Debug.Log ("Cube 2 hit");
        atCube2 = true;
        isGrounded = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting. Two things: 1) you don't need `== true `. 2) what if `atCube1` and `atCube2` are both true?

Comment: Does your JumpRight function reset the atCube1 and isGrounded field values?

Comment: Hi @Wai, thanks for responding, I dont think atCube1 and 2 can be true at the same time, as this is in the OnCollisionEnter function, please see it below, void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
 {
  Debug.Log("OnCollisionEnter");

  
  if (col.gameObject.name == "Cube 1"){
   Debug.Log ("++++++ C U B E 1   H I T ++++++++");

   atCube1 = true;
   isGrounded = true;
  
  }

  if(col.gameObject.name == "Cube 2"){

   Debug.Log ("Cube 2 hit");
   atCube2 = true;
   isGrounded = true;
   
  } }

Comment: Hi @Neil, No the jump functions do not reset the atCube1 and isGrounded , these values are set to true in the OnCollisionEnter() function. Should they be set to false in the OnCollisionExit() function or else where? Thanks!

Comment: Hi again. Could you edit your question to include that code instead of having it as a comment? That'll make it easier for others to read. BTW, when does `OnCollisionEnter` get called? If it's inside the loop, then both bool values will be true at some point.

Comment: ... You can easily check this by setting `atCube2` to false when on cube 1 and `atCube1` to false when on cube 2.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, thanks for your helpful advice, i will give that a try and let you know.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, hi, the OnCollisionEnter function is built in, which can be amended, it automatically tells the system when two objects touch. I will try out your advice and Neil's. Thankyou both!

Comment: Why do you call Jump method (e.g. JumpRight()) ten times in a row in one frame? And do you set your booleans (isGrounded, atCube1...) to false in OnCollisionExit?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, hi Wai, thanks for your advice, the code is working:).

Comment: @NeilCross, hi Neil, thanks for your advice, the code is working:).

Comment: @SeanEd-Man, hi Sean, thanks for your concern, issue is resolved .

Answer (score 0):

You should make `atCube1 = false;` after it left cube1(do it for cube2 too). Also you can add `isGrounded = false;` when it does not collides anything.

1-You start at cube1, `atCube1 = true`

2-Jump to cube2, `atCube1 = true`, `atCube2 = true`

3- Jump to cube1 again, it jumps left because still `atCube2 = true` . In fact, it jumps right at first and then jumps left because of your `if` statements' order. Just add `false` values to booleans to fix it.